# How can I define PlanningVariable dynamicly, such as a map?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a problem with OptaPlanner. I need to design a PlanningEntity with dynamic PlanningVariables. So that I can reuse the PlanningEntity in different projects.
Maybe like this :

```
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;

import java.util.Map;

@PlanningEntity
public class Lesson {

    private Long id;
    /**
     * key: room value: Room Object
     * key: timeslot value: TimeSlot Object
     */
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "planningVariableMapRange")
    private Map<String, Object> planningVariableMap;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lesson" + "(" + id + ")";
    }

    // ********************************
    // Getters and setters
    // ********************************

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getPlanningVariableMap() {
        return planningVariableMap;
    }

    public void setPlanningVariableMap(Map<String, Object> planningVariableMap) {
        this.planningVariableMap = planningVariableMap;
    }
}
```

How could I achive that ?

I've also write a PlanningSolution like below.

```
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningEntityCollectionProperty;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningScore;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.PlanningSolution;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.ProblemFactProperty;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange.ValueRangeProvider;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@PlanningSolution
public class TimeTable {

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "planningVariableMapRange")
    @ProblemFactProperty
    private Map<String, List<Object>> valueProvider;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Lesson> lessonList;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;


    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return score;
    }


    public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
        this.score = score;
    }


    public Map<String, List<Object>> getValueProvider() {
        return valueProvider;
    }

    public void setValueProvider(Map<String, List<Object>> valueProvider) {
        this.valueProvider = valueProvider;
    }
}
```

Then I don't know what to do. Apparently, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it won't work. OptaPlanner (nor [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/) for that matter) is not designed to work like that. You will have to figure out a way of sharing logic between entities in a way that, in the end, each entity only has the variables it needs and they are each annotated separately.

Inheritance is probably the best way to go. You can have all the methods on the supertype, and then annotate the getters on the concrete subtype for the variables you need in that particular problem. This will ensure most of your code is not duplicated, but some boilerplate will remain. (Such as the concrete solution and entity subtypes.) I'd argue this is a small cost to pay.